# JSP trying to convert a String array into a Int array

Tags: java, arrays, jsp, tomcat, servlets

I've been trying to convert a String array I got using request.getParameterValues(), taking each individual value using a normal array (example[1, 2, 3...]) and putting it inside a Integer.parseInt() and it keeps giving me this error:

> Interger cannot be resolved

I'm going insane. This is the specific part of the code:

```
int mat1[] = new int[(matrix1.getCols() * matrix1.getRows())];
int mat2[] = new int[(matrix2.getCols() * matrix2.getRows())];

if(request.getParameterValues("el") != null)
{
    String str[] = request.getParameterValues("el");
    for(int a = 0; a < (matrix1.getCols() * matrix1.getRows()); a++)
        mat1[a] = Interger.parseInt(str[a].trim()); 
}
if(request.getParameterValues("el2") != null)
{
    String str2[] = request.getParameterValues("el2");
    for(int a2 = 0; a2 < (matrix2.getCols() * matrix2.getRows()); a2++){
        mat2[a2] = Interger.parseInt(str2[a2].trim());
}
```

"el" and "el2" come from here:

```
for(int n = 0; n < matrix1.getRows(); n++){ %><br><%
    for(int i = 0; i < matrix1.getCols(); i++){ %>
    <form method=get>
    <tr><input type=number name=el value=0></tr>
```

...

```
for(int n2 = 0; n2 < matrix2.getRows(); n2++){ %><br><%
    for(int i2 = 0; i2 < matrix2.getCols(); i2++){;%>
    <tr><input type=number name=el2 value=0></tr>
```

pls help me

Comment: It's Integer, not Interger, as it said in the error.

Comment: You have a typo - it's Integer, not Interger.  The error message is telling you it doesn't know what Interger is (i.e. it cannot be resolved).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the error say it all, you made a typo.

> **Interger** cannot be resolved

```
Interger.parseInt
```

Should be

```
Integer.parseInt
```

Comment: Oh my god... so much time wasted.